# Counter example to existence of Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Every open cover $X = U \cup V$ gives an exact sequence (called *mayer vietoris sequence*)
$$
\ldots \to H_n(U \cap V) \to H_n(U) \oplus H_n(V) \to H_n(X) \to H_{n-1}(U \cap V) \to \ldots
$$

Do $U$ and $V$ really need to be open sets covering $X$? Are there counter examples for what can go wrong if they aren't?

The proof just requires that $H_k(U,U \cap V) \to H_k(X,V)$ is an isomorphism for all $k$, which follows in the above situation by excision. Are there interesting examples for $(X,U,V)$ when this isn't the case and there is no mayer vietoris sequence? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the case where $X = \mathbb{R}^2, U = {(0,0)}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$. We now have that $U \cap V = \emptyset. $

Then $H_1(X) = 0, H_1(U \cap V) = 0$, which by exactness implies $H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V) = 0.$

But, $H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V) = 0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$

So the sequence cannot be exact.